# Custom navigation Titanium

Tags: menu, navigation, titanium, customization, tabbar

I need do a very special nav or tab bar for a app, I looked [this](https://vimeo.com/46716470) but I not have idea how to make some similar, I work with Titanium mobile, someone with experience could tell me how to make some similar with Titanium, or if someone have other navigation bar more complex that the examples on the kitchensink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where I'd start.  Understand that that video is obviously a complex interface and will definitely take work on your part.

This (http://softlywired.com/ticustommenu/) piece of code will get you started, but you will need to go way beyond it writing that interface control.  I'd then move on to creating the boxes that pop up, without animation, down the center.  After that was working, I'd look at animating them and adding the event listeners to it.

You'd be a star in the Titanium community if you got it working and released the source code to it.

Comment: Thanks bro, I began with a custom menu using the animations that includes on the api of Titanium, certainly is more work that the i thought, but i believe than the result could be very interest.